# why the use of self.foo = self.foo in __init__ in Python class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I see several  times that people write the following in their **init** function.

```
def __init__(self,**attr):
 self.foo = self.foo
```

Is it a (useful) trick?
Can someone explain it to me? Thanks.

Updated.

For example, in graph.py (for defining Graph class) in [networkx](https://github.com/networkx/networkx)
I see the following.

```
def __init__(self, incoming_graph_data=None, **attr):
 self.graph_attr_dict_factory = self.graph_attr_dict_factory
 self.node_dict_factory = self.node_dict_factory
```

Comment: No, I don't think you have seen that.  Maybe you have seen `self.foo = foo`, but what you have written will cause a runtime error.

Comment: With this snippet, unless `self.foo` is declared before `__init__` is called, this would raise an `AttributeError`.

Comment: Dear  blarg, Tim, Please see my update

Comment: Code should only be posted as text, never screenshots. See [Why should I not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122)

Comment: That said, NetworkX is doing something interesting here in the interests of making a function subclasses can override. It's not a general-use practice, but very much a special case (they're specifying `graph_attr_dict_factory = dict` earlier in the class definition), and it probably makes more sense to ask "why is networkx doing this?" rather than "why do this in general?"

Comment: ...indeed, I'm disappointed nobody asked why this code was necessary [when it went through code review](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/3205); because I'm pretty sure it is not in fact useful and could be removed without any change in behavior.

Comment: In hte networkx case, `graph_attr_dict_factory` starts as a class variable holding a function for building nodes. By default, its just a dict, but class inheritors can change that. So far, it makes sense. Its a normal way to add an external function such as `dict` to a class that can be changed in subclasses. `self.graph_attr_dict_factory = self.graph_attr_dict_factory` first resolves to the class variable and then assigns its value to the like-named variable in the instance dicitonary. I haven't figured out how this is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a bit more code, its use may make some sense in two separate cases, although it's still not always the best way to achieve what it achieves:

```
class MyClass:
    baz = 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.baz = self.baz
        self._foo = None
        self.bar = None
        self.foo = self.foo

    @property
    def foo(self):
        if self._foo is None:
            self._foo = 1
        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self.bar = 0
        self._foo = value


m1 = MyClass()
m2 = MyClass()
print(m1.foo, m1.bar, m1.baz)
m1.baz = 2
MyClass.baz = 3
print(m1.baz, m2.baz, MyClass.baz)
```

A bit contrived, but what `self.foo = self.foo` would achieve is that both the getter and setter for the `.foo` property will have been called.

People saying `.foo` cannot be accessed at that point and would raise an `AttributeError` are right in the limited case you're sharing, but of course defining a property makes it available in the constructor as well, as the example here shows. I kept the code a bit cleaner by defining `._foo` first, but of course you could just first define it in the setter, that's not recommended though.

That setters and getters are run is mainly important if they have side effects, which is one reason to use properties (another common one being that you want to limit access, or restrict possible values).

Edit: The example in `networkx` is reassigning a class attribute to an instance attribute (I wasn't aware that worked until I tried). See the result of the final `print()` in my example:

```
m1.baz = 2
MyClass.baz = 3
print(m1.baz, m2.baz, MyClass.baz)
```

Result:

```
2 1 3
```

The reason `networkx` might be doing this is to allow you to supply a different Graph factory method, without affecting the class - only your instance would get a new one if you assign to its `graph_attr_dict_factory`, but it is initialised with the class factory method.

However, note that even if `networkx` didn't set it up like that in the constructor, a user could still assign a new factory to the instance later and see the same behaviour - the only real difference is that the instance wouldn't have an instance attribute up to that point and would have been accessing the class attribute instead. It's possible that other code relies on that distinction, so removing the assignment *could* have an impact elsewhere, but it does nothing for the immediate functionality of the class itself.

Comment: The OP is asking about this [in the context of the networkx library](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/3205/files), which is not using properties in the code at hand.

Comment: Did you read the entire answer? Also, did you realise the first part was posted before OP asked that? All the same, the exact reason why `networkx` does so is covered, if you read beyond the first few lines.